# How does the "spotlight method" of recovering trauma work?

Tags: cortex-plus, marvel-heroic-roleplaying

I'm looking at page OM28 here:

> If you don’t relish the idea of sitting out an entire Act or it doesn’t make sense in the story for the Watcher to skip ahead several weeks in a single Transition Scene, you can opt for the spotlight route. The Watcher frames an Action Scene featuring your hero in which your trauma makes things worse for you, i.e., it’s used against you in the opposition dice pools.

I'm not sure what this extra action scene should entail. If only the affected hero is involved, then the rest of the heroes are going to be stuck waiting. If it's simply the next action scene, then the watcher is probably going to be rolling the hero's trauma die anyway.

So: what does the "spotlight route" actually entail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "spotlight scene" doesn't necessarily exclude the other heroes, but the focus of the attention should be on the wounded character; the trade-off here is one *additional* dangerous scene for him or her rather than losing the character for the rest of the Act or moving the timeline forward enough for them to heal. (It shouldn't be the next Action scene you've already planned.) The other characters might be well served in creating Assets or Resources for the damaged character to use.

If the trauma is Physical, you might introduce a long-standing nemesis who comes into the scene at just the wrong time. If Emotional or Mental, it's a good time to activate a seldom-used Distinction or Limit.